How to create a new Intellij plugin LanguageFileType based on Kotlin?

I want to create a new LanguageFileType to support Kotlin inspection on my script language file with an extension "engine.kts".
but there is an issue with getting the KotlinLanguage instance.
I already tried this way but it throws NullPointerException.
        Language.findLanguageByID("kotlin")



Add Kotlin Dependency to your plugin.xml file.



Add compileOnly configuration to Gradle project dependency.

compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler")

